# Get transcational email id by name

Tags: php, email, magento, backend, magento-1.9

Does someone know how do I get the id of an email by name set on backend? I have an email created in backend in transactional emails that I want to send it programatically, but the id of it may differ depending on the instance that I'm on (local, live, stage), and I can only provide the same name for it.
I have this:

```
Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->sendTransactional(
$templateId, 
$sender, 
$recepientEmail, 
$recepientName, 
$vars, 
$store);
```

And I need to find out $templateId and I only know that I saved the mail with name "Tests".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check the codes below. any way this is my first answer on stackoverflow.

```
$templateName = "Tests";
$templateID = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadByCode($templateName)->getId();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get email template:

```
$templateName = “Test”;
$emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadByCode($templateName);
```

Get id:

```
$templateId = $emailTemplate->getId();
```

And then send email on your way:

```
Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->sendTransactional(
    $templateId, 
    $sender, 
    $recepientEmail, 
    $recepientName, 
    $vars, 
    $store
);
```

or use "my" method:

```
$vars = array('key' => 'value');
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
$recipientEmail = 'some@email.com';
$recipientName = 'Some Name';
$emailTemplate->setSenderEmail(Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email', $storeId)); 
$emailTemplate->setSenderName(Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/name', $storeId));    
$emailTemplate->send($recipientEmail, $recipientName, $vars);
```